# peculiar syntax for function within()

Tags: r, syntax

I came across this fantastic function called

> within {base}

I use it more often now than the much hyped

> mutate {dplyr}

My question is, why is **within()** having such a peculiar format with assignment operators used **<-** instead of the usual **=** for args; How is it different from **mutate** other than what is given in this fantastic article I found. I am interested to know the underlying mechanism.
[Article of Bob Munchen - 2013](http://r4stats.com/2013/01/22/comparing-tranformation-styles/)

Comment: The syntax of `within()` is no other than for other functions. But you have only one expression to evaluate, if you want more to be done then you have to form this one expression: `{ ...}`. IMHO you better compare `mutate()` with `transform()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `within` takes an expression as second argument. That expression is essentially a codeblock, best contained within curly brackets `{}`.

In this codeblock, you can assign new variables, change values and the likes. The variables can be used in the codeblock as objects.

`mutate` on the other hand takes a set of arguments for the mutation. These arguments have to be named after the variable that should be created, and get the value for that variable as the value.

So :

```
mutate(iris, ratio = Sepal.Length/Petal.Length)
# and
within(iris, {ratio = Sepal.Length/Petal.Length})
```

give the same result. The problem starts when you remove the curly brackets:

```
> within(iris, ratio = Sepal.Length/Petal.Length)
Error in eval(substitute(expr), e) : argument is missing, with no default
```

The curly brackets enclosed an expression (piece of code), and hence `within()` worked correctly. If you don't use the `{}`, then R semantics reads that last command as "call the function `within` with `iris` as first argument and a second argument called `ratio` set to `Sepal.Length/Petal.Length`". And as the function `within()` doesn't have an argument `ratio`, that one is ignored. Instead, `within` looks for the expression that should be the second argument. But it can't find that one, so that explains the error.

So there's little peculiar about it. Both functions just have different arguments. All the rest is pretty much how R deals with arguments.

Comment: Fantastic examples @Joris ...
Between the two answers above, I have got everything. 

PS: I am new to Stack Overflow hence cannot upvote you (yet).

BTW why does your name not pop up in SO when I precede it with @?

Answer (score 1):

Args of `within` are not assigned with `<-` but with the usual `=`.

Let's see the first example in your link:

```
mydata.new <- within(mydata, {
+              x2 <- x  ^ 2
+              x3 <- x2 + 100
+              } )
```

Here,

```
{
 x2 <- x  ^ 2
 x3 <- x2 + 100
}
```

is just an argument of the function (an `R expression`). Nor `x2` nor `x3` are arguments to `within`. The function could have been called in that way instead to make it clearer:

```
mydata.new <- within(data = mydata, expr = {
            x2 <- x  ^ 2
            x3 <- x2 + 100
            })
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks, @Pop for the quick clarification. Plus 1.
PS. I still don't have enough reputation points to upvote you but will do when I have them.

Comment: You're right. I modified it. It's because the `r_expression` is evaluated when the first line is run and not in the `within` function...